# Seeking arcpy.SetParameterAsText equivalent in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, parameters, calculate-values

I know it sounds weird, but I would need a tool made with ModelBuilder that output two parameters:

1. a layer
2. a message (a string)

The constraint derives from the need to share it as a Geoprocessing service which a web application can use, but this application requires the two aforementioned outputs.

I know I can do it using Python, but I am explicitly asking if this is doable from ModelBuilder as well.

Basically, what I would like to translate from arcpy to ModelBuilder tool is:

```
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0, my_layer)
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, my_message)
```

What I have now is a super simple MB tool like the one below:

[image: Model]

However, I am not aware of any method to set the "String" variable as my output.

---

Using [@Hornbydd’s suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336173/seeking-arcpy-setparameterastext-equivalent-in-modelbuilder#comment548336_336173), I finally managed to make it work using the Calculate Value tool in ModelBuilder.

The way I did it is shown in the picture below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What process in the model would generate the string?

Comment: That's the my main doubt. In python I would just need to store whatever string to a variable and then I can expose it as an output of my model with `arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0, my_message)`. I don't see such a possibility with MB, am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe the question would be: do any of the existing ArcToolbox tools output a string or a message so that I can use it in my model?

Comment: Have a look at the model only _calculate value_ tool, that could output a string which you could set as a parameter.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. If you want to post it as an answer 'll be happy to accept it. I'll edit my question to include my final model when I have time.